# Jenkins Artifactory Plugin File Specs with subprojects

Tags: java, jenkins, artifactory

I am using Jenkins with [Artifactory plugin](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Jenkins+Artifactory+Plug-in) to publish artifacts.

I build application with Java and Gradle. Artifacts are located in `build/libs/` folder as by convention. Publishing with specified File Specs works if I have multi module project.

```
root
|--proj1
|--proj2
|--...
```

File Specs pattern looks like (note com.rivancic is group for Artifactory repository):

```
"files": [
  {
    "target": "test-repo/com/rivancic/{1}/1.0.0/{2}-1.0.0{3}",
    "pattern": "/home-dir/com/rivancic/(*)/build/libs/(*)-1.0.0(*)"
  }
]
```

Here first wildcard is resolved to `proj1` or `proj2` and artifacts are uploaded to specific modules.

**Problem**

The problem I face is when using multi module project with **nested projects**.

```
root
|--proj1
   |--subproj11
   |--subproj12
|--proj2
|--...
```

Now with the same pattern for the first subproject11 first wildcard is resolved to `proj1/subproj11` instead of only `subproj11`. This resolves to invalid artifact module name and Artifactory throws exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Failed to deploy file. Status code: 409 Response message: Artifactory returned the following errors: 
The target deployment path 'com/rivancic/project1/subproject11/1.0.0/subproject11-1.0.0.pom' does not match the POM's expected path prefix 'com/rivancic/subproject11/1.0.0'. Please verify your POM content for correctness and make sure the source path is a valid Maven repository root path. Status code: 409
```

Is there a way I can define a pattern in File Specs that it will always take just the last part of path, the final subproject instead of the whole path for the above structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 2 different File Specs or 2 different File Spec group: One for multi modules and the other for multi projects.

For multi projects, use the following exmple:

```json
"files": [
  {
    "target": "test-repo/com/rivancic/{1}/1.0.0/{2}-1.0.0{3}",
    "pattern": "/home-dir/com/rivancic/*/(*)/build/libs/(*)-1.0.0(*)"
  }
]
```

Explanation -
In `/*/(*)` part of the spec, the first asterisk is parsed as a regular wildcard, and the one surrounded by parenthesis, is used as a [Placeholder](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Using+File+Specs#UsingFileSpecs-UsingPlaceholders).

More information about File Specs can be found under [Using File Specs](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Using+File+Specs).

Comment: Thanks yahavi. Your solution works for sub-subprojects. Now I have problem with first level subprojects. I can't figure out how to deploy them correctly. If I add another file spec group for first level subproject like I described above, I again get the exception as pattern with * traverses through all subdirectories.

Comment: Can you try to add `"recursive": false` below the pattern?

Comment: I saw all those flags but couldn't really imagine how they should be used. With two groups and recursive flag enabled this really works. Thanks yahavi! Now at the end I will probably not use Artifactory plugin at all and invoke directly Gradle publish task which is much more intuitive from developers perspective.

Comment: @RenatoIvancic this is quite a complicated case. File Spec should be the easiest and most intuitive way to download/upload files to Artifactory. You may find that using the Gradle task to upload would be more complicated to use.